# Cannot read property 'initialize' of undefined - SailsJs

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I'm trying to create a sailsjs webapi with authentication.

My api works fine until I add packages for authentication without changing anything else.

My api give a 500 Internal Server Error after I run this command:

```
sudo npm install sails-permissions sails-auth@2.1.1 lodash sails-mongo --save
```

I have the following error:

```
error: Sending 500 ("Server Error") response: 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'initialize' of undefined
at module.exports (/home/rick/Documents/apexBackend/node_modules/sails-auth/dist/api/policies/passport.js:35:11)
at routeTargetFnWrapper (/usr/lib/node_modules/sails/lib/router/bind.js:179:5)
at callbacks (/usr/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:164:37)
at param (/usr/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:138:11)
at pass (/usr/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:145:5)
at nextRoute (/usr/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:100:7)
at callbacks (/usr/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:167:11)
at /usr/lib/node_modules/sails/lib/router/bind.js:187:7
at module.exports (/home/rick/Documents/apexBackend/node_modules/sails-auth/dist/api/policies/basicAuth.js:13:12)
at routeTargetFnWrapper (/usr/lib/node_modules/sails/lib/router/bind.js:179:5)
at callbacks (/usr/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:164:37)
at param (/usr/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:138:11)
at pass (/usr/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:145:5)
at nextRoute (/usr/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:100:7)
at callbacks (/usr/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:167:11)
at /usr/lib/node_modules/sails/lib/router/bind.js:187:7 [TypeError: Cannot read property 'initialize' of undefined]
```

These are my dependencies:

```
"ejs": "~0.8.4",
"grunt": "0.4.2",
"grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.5.0",
"grunt-contrib-coffee": "~0.10.1",
"grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.3.0",
"grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.5.0",
"grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.9.0",
"grunt-contrib-jst": "~0.6.0",
"grunt-contrib-less": "0.11.1",
"grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.4.0",
"grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.5.3",
"grunt-sails-linker": "~0.9.5",
"grunt-sync": "~0.0.4",
"include-all": "~0.1.3",
"lodash": "^3.10.1",
"rc": "~0.5.0",
"sails": "~0.11.3",
"sails-auth": "^2.1.1",
"sails-disk": "~0.10.0",
"sails-mongo": "^0.11.5",
"sails-permissions": "^2.1.11"
```

Comment: There's an open bug in sails-permissions that may be related: https://github.com/tjwebb/sails-permissions/issues/144

Comment: @mwobey: I already found that post but how can I find a solution for this? Just by going back to a previous version?

Comment: The bug described in that github issue is still open -- you can try another version of the software (the maintainer appears to recommend trying to upgrade to 0.12.0-rc3), but ultimately the only solutions are either:

* wait for the problem to be fixed
* fix the problem in sails-permissions and make a pull request
* use another library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it using this command:

```
 sudo npm install git://github.com/balderdashy/sails.git#master -g
```

Latest version of sails works again.